# Magento2 .htaccess

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite, redirect, htaccess

I want to redirect another url.

```
 https://example.com/store1/lstoreviewcode/ 
 https://example.com/store2/cstoreviewcode/
```

**to replace with**

```
 https://example.com/store1/storeviewcode/
 https://example.com/store2/storeviewcode/
```

I want to change only URL, content are same.

Answer (score 1):

You can manage URL rewrites in `Marketing -> (SEO & Search) -> URL rewrites` please see [Magento docs](https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/marketing/url-rewrite.html) for more information.

Comment: I was already tried but not working...

Comment: @AnasMansuri what did you try and how did it not work?

Comment: I don't have any https://example.com/store1/storeviewcode/ path for this. I want only redirect here.. for same content. which is loaded in ******/lstoreviewcode

Comment: It looks like you are including the domain, that won't work.  If you set Request Path = `store1/lstoreviewcode` and Target Path = 'store1/storeviewcode/' what happens?  Also as you are mentioning store code how about just `lstoreviewcode` and `storeviewcode`?

Comment: I was done, its return 404..

Comment: What redirect type did you use? And if it is going to a 404 - then it must be redirecting to the wrong url... what is that? compared to what it should be?

Answer (score 0):

Add this in `.htaccess`

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example.com/store1/lstoreviewcode/ $ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/store1/lstoreviewcode/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example.com/store2/cstoreviewcode/ $ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/store2/storeviewcode/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I'm trying but its return 500